# How does electron handle global dependencies

Tags: electron

I'm new to electron. I'm building an app that uses ffmpeg and sox, which are installed globally. How do I guarantee that these dependencies will be installed on the users computer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is not specific to electron, but can help
http://12factor.net/dependencies

Answer (score 0):

There could be two kind of system level dependencies:

1. NPM based package expected to be installed at a system level
2. Non NPM package, like a system level library(in your case ffmpeg)

For NPM based package, you can do a peer dependency like the following:

```
{
  ....
  "peerDependencies": {
    "chai": "1.x"
  }
  ....

}
```

For non NPM package, usual pattern is to check this during your application start flow and inform the user if it's not available.

Answering specific to ffmpeg, following should help:

```
/**
   * Check for ffmpeg availability
   *
   * If the FFMPEG_PATH environment variable is set, try to use it.
   * If it is unset or incorrect, try to find ffmpeg in the PATH instead.
   *
   * @method FfmpegCommand#_getFfmpegPath
   * @param {Function} callback callback with signature (err, path)
   * @private
   */
  proto._getFfmpegPath = function(callback) {
    if ('ffmpegPath' in cache) {
      return callback(null, cache.ffmpegPath);
    }

async.waterfall([
  // Try FFMPEG_PATH
  function(cb) {
    if (process.env.FFMPEG_PATH) {
      fs.exists(process.env.FFMPEG_PATH, function(exists) {
        if (exists) {
          cb(null, process.env.FFMPEG_PATH);
        } else {
          cb(null, '');
        }
      });
    } else {
      cb(null, '');
    }
  },

  // Search in the PATH
  function(ffmpeg, cb) {
    if (ffmpeg.length) {
      return cb(null, ffmpeg);
    }

    utils.which('ffmpeg', function(err, ffmpeg) {
      cb(err, ffmpeg);
    });
  }
], function(err, ffmpeg) {
  if (err) {
    callback(err);
  } else {
    callback(null, cache.ffmpegPath = (ffmpeg || ''));
  }
    });
  };
```

The above code is [taken from here](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/blob/e99e1956d4c2b7ebd68d09c83e796abc82d15b5b/lib/capabilities.js). [node-fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) is a nice project which works on top of ffmpeg. I believe, it will be a good reference for your project.

Comment: cool, but as I see, you just inform the user that he hasn't ffmpeg installed, is there a way for me to install it if it isn't installed?

Comment: it may be possible by over engineering the application logic. But do you really want to do that ? Is it the responsibility of the application to install these dependencies ? Usually, system level dependencies are informed to the user to take care of., May be, you can provide a link to ffmpeg download page. But I may not know the scope of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You could package the different installers for the dependencies with your app, then create a custom installer for your app that also launches the dependency installers in sequence, or simply prompt the user to install the dependencies themselves and link them to a download page.

There are lots of resources for creating installers, try a google search for `electron installer` for your specific platform.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I'm late to the party but just in case this is still relevant - I've created `ffbinaries` module specifically for this purpose.

You can check it out on npm, it'll simply download the binaries on user machine during app boot, the platform will be detected automatically (you can override it though if you're planning to include it in CI of some sort).